# Making a no parameter type have "defaults"

Tags: types, julia

I essentially want to do the following:

```
typealias CVODE_BDF CVODE_BDF{:Newton,:Dense}
```

that is, allow a user to pass to my function `CVODE_BDF` and, if they did not set any of the type parameters, interpret it as `CVODE_BDF{:Newton,:Dense}`. I know that the `typealias` doesn't actually work, but is there a way to simulate this? Like in the function, read `T.parameters[1]` and somehow see that it was empty?

Comment: could this be useful? https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl

Comment: That's different. That handles fields but not type parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this if the function accepts *objects of that type*, rather than the type itself. E.g.

```
type MyObject{T}
end


const DefaultMyObject = MyObject{Int64}()

f{T}(x::MyObject{T}=DefaultMyObject) = T

f(), f(MyObj{Float64}())
```

gives

```
(Int64,Float64)
```

Comment: This is the most clear answer and gets right to the point that I think the issue I was having was a design error, which is fixed by having the function accept instances of the type rather than the type itself. This answer spurred an API discussion, and after some work, I think we're better off. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Hm, if this is the answer you had in mind you might want to change the title / question a bit, since right now it's asking a different question. Perhaps something like "How to make default function arguments of a parameterised type also take default parameter values"

Comment: This isn't the answer I had in mind. But it's the answer that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is setting the type parameters (`{:Newton,:Dense}`) via [Constructors](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/constructors/).

Here is an example of the rational number type defined in Julia (rational.jl):

```
immutable Rational{T<:Integer} <: Real
    num::T
    den::T

    function Rational(num::T, den::T)
        if num == 0 && den == 0
            error("invalid rational: 0//0")
        end
        g = gcd(den, num)
        num = div(num, g)
        den = div(den, g)
        new(num, den)
    end
end
```

In your example, you could define a constructor function in you `CVODE_BDF` type definition and check for the types and fall back to `{:Newton,:Dense}` if they are not set.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work for you?

```
type A{T, S} end
```

Function implementation:

```
f{T, S}(::Type{A{T,S}}) = T, S
```

Wrappers that set the default values:

```
f(::Type{A}) = f(A{1, 1})
f{T}(::Type{A{T}}) = f(A{T, 1})
f{S}(::Type{A{:default, S}}) = f(A{1, S})
```

Result:

```
f(A)                 # (1,1)
f(A{3,4})            # (3,4)
f(A{0})              # (0,1)
f(A{:default, 2})    # (1,2)
```

Because the last call is a bit ugly, objects are probably the better choice if maximum flexibility is needed. Additionally, constructors can enforce constraints on the parameters, so that they don't need to be checked in the function.

Edit:

If your function has more than one argument, adding methods for every combination of parameters is too much work. Instead, one can define a default method for each type (just one parameter for brevity):

```
type A{T} end
type B{T} end

default{T}(::Type{A{T}}) = A{T}
default(::Type{A}) = A{1}
default{T}(::Type{B{T}}) = B{T}
default(::Type{B}) = B{1}

f{T,S}(::Type{A{T}}, ::Type{B{S}}) = T*S
f{T<:A, S<:B}(a::Type{T}, b::Type{S}) = f(default(a), default(b))
```

On a current nightly, this has no runtime overhead:

```
julia> @code_llvm f(A,B)

define i64 @julia_f_62099(%jl_value_t*, %jl_value_t*) #0 {
top:
  ret i64 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Yes there is.*** If you do `Type{CVODE_BDF}` you can then check the resulting object's parameters. If `CVODE_BDF` was 'empty' this will return a `CVODE_BDF` type with generic parameters, otherwise they will be the specific ones used.

Example (using `Array` since I don't have `CVODE_BDF` handy):

```
julia> Type{Array}.parameters
svec(Array{T,N})

julia> Type{Array{Float64, Int64}}.parameters
svec(Array{Float64,Int64})
```

Example function:

```
function f{T}(t::T)
  if Type(t).parameters == Type(Array).parameters
    t = Array{Int64, 1};
  end
  return t;
end
```

```
julia> f(Array{Int64, 1})
Array{Int64,1}

julia> f(Array{Float64, 1})
Array{Float64,1}

julia> f(Array)
Array{Int64,1}
```